# Пропала анимация текста с помощью @keyframes после добавления модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, веб-программирование

уважаемые программисты! Пропала анимация текста, после того как добавил модальное окно регистрации и входа. Буду благодарен за помощь!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,300&family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Night Music | Music for deep thoughts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h2 class="logo">Night Music</h2>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="./about.html">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <button class="btnLogin-popup">Login</button>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="title">Music for deep thoughts</h1>
        <a href="./music_list.html" class="gotolisten-btn"
          >Go to listen &#9658;</a
        >
        <span class="icon-close"
          ><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon
        ></span>
        <div class="form-box login">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="icon"
                ><ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon
              ></span>
              <input type="email" required />
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="icon"
                ><ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon
              ></span>
              <input type="password" required />
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="remember-forgot">
              <label><input type="checkbox" /> Remember me</label>
              <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
            <div class="login-register">
              <p>
                Don't have account?
                <a href="#" class="register-link"> Register</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="form-box register">
          <h2>Registration</h2>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="icon"
                ><ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon
              ></span>
              <input type="text" required />
              <label>Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="icon"
                ><ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon
              ></span>
              <input type="password" required />
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="remember-forgot">
              <label
                ><input type="checkbox" /> I agree to the rules for site</label
              >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
            <div class="login-register">
              <p>
                Already have account? <a href="#" class="login-link"> Login</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url("./img/main_img.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  user-select: none;
}

.navigation a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 1000;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navigation a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.navigation a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 1000;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -100px 0 0 #fff;
  background: #fff;
  color: #8400ff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 440px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .5s ease, height .2s ease;  
}

.wrapper.active-popup {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper.active {
  height: 520px;
}

.title {
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 20ch;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: printed-text 3s ease;
}

@keyframes printed-text {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show-btn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.txt {
  color: #fff;
}

.gotolisten-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;

  font-weight: 300;
  animation: show-btn 0.2s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  width: 100%;

  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.wrapper .form-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.wrapper .form-box.login {
  transition: transform .18s ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.login {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(-400px);
}

.wrapper .form-box.register {
  position: absolute;
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.register {
  transition: transform .18s ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper .icon-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #162938;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #162938;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-box h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #162938;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #162938;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.input-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #162938;
  font-weight: 500;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.input-box input:focus~label,
.input-box input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
}

.input-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #162938;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.input-box .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #162938;
  line-height: 57px;
}

.remember-forgot {
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #162938;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: -15px 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.remember-forgot label input {
  accent-color: #162938;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.remember-forgot a {
  color: #162938;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.remember-forgot a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: #162938;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.login-register {
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #162938;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 25px 0 10px;
}

.login-register p a {
  color: #162938;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.login-register p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

script.js

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const loginLink = document.querySelector('.login-link');
const registerLink = document.querySelector('.register-link');
const btnPopup = document.querySelector('.btnLogin-popup');
const iconClose = document.querySelector('.icon-close');

registerLink.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.add('active');
})

loginLink.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.remove('active');
})

btnPopup.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.add('active-popup');
})

iconClose.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.remove('active-popup');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

В css необходимо явно указать, что при сбросе класса элемента `active-popup` анимацию необходимо сбросить на значение `none`, а при открытии модального окна снова добавить анимацию элементу `.title`

Самое простое решение, включить строки ниже в css. Однако можно внедрить их в существующие правила

```
.wrapper .title {
  animation: none;
}
.wrapper.active-popup .title {
  animation: printed-text 3s ease;
}
```